# lvalue required as left operand of assignment error in c

Tags: c, lvalue

I have to write a program that compares 3 integers. I do not understand why I cant assign the variable a to to either min or max variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, max, notmax;
    printf("enter first integer\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("enter second integer\n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("enter third integer\n");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    a > b ? a = max : a = notmax ;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A look at the precedence and associativity might help you understand what's happening here. the assignment has lower precedence than the ?: operator.
so the statement

```
a > b ? a = max : a = notmax ;
```

is seen as:

((`a > b ? a = max : a) = notmax );`

but once you use brackets at appropriate place as shown below, everything works fine:

```
a > b ? a = max : (a = notmax) ;
```

or maybe something even like:

(a > b `? (a = max) : (a = notmax)) ;`

which should force precedence the way you want it. Using the brackets will help a lot in evaluating the compound statements.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer explains that the error you're seeing is due to operator precedence between `?:` and `=`.  What it doesn't mention is what would be the best fix.

The `?:` operator evaluates to either the value of second or the value of the third part.  So it can be used to choose either `max` or `notmax` and assign it to `a`.

```
a = a > b ? max : notmax;
```

However, your code *still* has a problem because `max` and `notmax` have not been initialized, so their values are **indeterminate** and reading them can lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  Before running this state, you need to make sure both of these variables have been assigned a value.